# using cmd to create .txt containing url based on ipconfig and modem-required info

Tags: parsing, text, merge, cmd

I'm not too familiar with cmd or anything, but I have done some research and put together a bit of what I want.  This .bat I'm trying to make would take the output of ipconfig/all and select the mac address and ip address of the ethernet adapter and insert them in key locations in a pre-prescribed url for those instances when a computer doesn't automatically redirect to the front page of my hotel's internet billing setup.  this is not official work; I am only trying to "ease my burden" a bit and save time typing.

the full address I need to create in a .txt is 000.000.000.00/defaulta.php?mac=xxxxxxxxxxxx&ip=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx

everything but the mac and ip address (both listed as x's) are exactly as they need to be in every case.  the ip address shown censored with 0's is intentionally changed for security reasons, and no work needs to be done for that.  I have been able to create a simple .bat to create an output of the ipconfig data onto any user's desktop for easy access:

```
@echo off
ipconfig/all > %userprofile%\Desktop\url_address.txt
```

I have tried using other parsing solutions to get the data that I need, but the one easiest for me to adapt ([linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569640/dos-batch-command-to-read-some-info-from-text-file)) would only output the last instance, not the first or any in between when I make the simplest substitution.  I could try to use one of the solutions for only selecting certain lines, but I've seen some computers listing their ethernet first and wireless second, while others list wireless first and ethernet second.  I need to parse based specifically on the ethernet lines, as wireless internet is not available in the rooms.

here's an example of the output from my personal pc:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : xxxx.net
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros AR8121/AR8113/AR8114 PCI-E Ethernet Controller
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%12(Preferred) 
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : xxx.xxx.xx.xxx(Preferred)
```

anyone who looks up their own and compares will see it's not all the same length, so parsing based on length of characters won't work as different guests will have different cards, etc.  this means I need to parse two specific points, the physical address for the mac in the url and the ipv4 address for the ip address in the url.  would this mean I have to make two texts, one for each parsing? and how will these two variables be able to be inserted into the final url?

so my main questions are:

1) is it possible to take the two parts I need from the ethernet data and insert them into the appropriate places in the required link and put it in a .txt, and if so, what exactly needs to be done?

2) does the full function I intend need to be done through several .txt files being written as the function progresses to the final solution, or can this all be output to one text file on the guest's desktop for less clutter and easier deletion?

Comment: What if your guest will find this file and change URL to another MAC or IP address? Will another guest get charged instead? You should NOT trust end station (Windows) to report this information.

Comment: On my machine, I've got VM software. As a result, I've got multiple networks and, consequently, multiple IPs. This is a dev PC, though, meaning it may have things a "normal" PC doesn't need (and doesn't have). Still, my question is whether such a situation should be expected/accounted for by the script, and if so, how you would be determining the "right" `IPv4 Address` line.

Comment: @ mvp, I know anyone can, if really "desperate" even undelete a file after I create it.  the thing about this situation is that all guests are directed to this site when they check in and log onto the internet, once per 24 hours (first time and each 24 hour renewal of access).  anyone with enough knowledge could experiment with macs and ip addresses based on the address shown in the address bar (yes, it actually shows in the address bar just like I mentioned above), but I think there's additional information not shown to a user, which is set for each individual modem in the rooms.  I heard ...

Comment: @mvp continued:  that they did this specific registration for each modem in each room, so nobody should be able to "hook another room up" with their charges, and if they could, blame the isp that's providing this service, since the mac and ip address are plainly displayed in the address bar.  I can't make them change it, and since nobody's changed it in over 6 years, I'd say it's secure enough.

Comment: @ Andriy, I just tried what I have so far in my own vm.  Since the ip in the vm isn't the same, I believe this wouldn't work for getting the proper url information, since trying to go to the internet access page through a wireless router also fails in most cases.  it must be direct access from the computer's ethernet to the modem for the service to activate without fail.  besides this, since my vm is winxp, I just discovered I can't output to text so easy.  my ">" is coming out as "1>" and cmd says the syntax is incorrect.  the output in txt is "Error: unrecongnized or incomplete command line"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was tl;dr.  Does this do what you're looking for?  Modify `xxxx.net` and `000.000.000.00` as appropriate.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set found=0
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:(" %%I in ('ipconfig /all') do (
    if !found!==1 (
        for /f %%x in ('echo "%%I" ^| find "Physical Address"') do set mac=%%J
        for /f %%x in ('echo "%%I" ^| findstr "IP[v4]*.Address"') do (
            set ip=%%J
            goto next
        )
    )
    for /f %%x in ('echo "%%J" ^| find /i "xxxx.net"') do set found=1
)
echo Couldn't scrape info.  Press any key to exit.
pause >NUL
goto :EOF

:next
set mac=%mac: =%
start http://000.000.000.00/defaulta.php?mac=%mac:-=%^&ip=%ip: =%
```

It performs an `ipconfig /all` and loops through the output, ignoring everything until it encounters `xxxx.net` (your connection-specific DNS suffix).  Then it looks for `Physical Address` and `IPv4` address from there.  Spaces have to be removed from both captures, and dashes removed from the MAC address, all through [variable string substitution](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php).  Then it launches the user's default web browser to visit the URL you built.

If you actually do need this URL written to a text file instead of launched, then change

```
start http://000.000.000.00/defaulta.php?mac=%mac:-=%^&ip=%ip: =%
```

to

```
echo http://000.000.000.00/defaulta.php?mac=%mac:-=%^&ip=%ip: =% >outfile.txt
```

Be sure to put a space before the `>` to make sure Windows redirects stdout to the text file rather than whatever number the IP address happens to end with.

---

#### UPDATE 2013.02.27:

The above stuff should work regardless of user access level (administrator or normal user).  If you want to simulate running as a non-privileged user, run the following command:

```
runas /trustlevel:0x20000 cmd
```

... to open a cmd prompt with restricted privileges.  Then you can see for yourself that `ipconfig /all` still works.

For what it's worth, `ipconfig /all` is not the only place to scrape the IP and MAC address.  If you'd like an alternative to the above script, try this one:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=={}," %%I in (
    'wmic nicconfig where ^(ipenabled^='TRUE' and dnsdomain is not null^) get ipaddress^, macaddress /format:list'
) do (
    if %%I==IPAddress set ip=%%~J
    if %%I==MACAddress set mac=%%J
)
start "" "http://000.000.000.00/defaulta.php?mac=%mac::=%&ip=%ip%"
```

As before, don't forget to change the IP address in the URL as appropriate.

---

#### Update 2013.03.29:

Well, since nothing else has worked for every client computer (as `wmic` will not work on WinXP Home), and just to see whether I could more than anything, here's another one to try -- a batch / JScript hybrid script.  Save this with a `.bat` extension and I think it should work on every version of Windows after 98 and ME (Mistake Edition, if I recall correctly).

As before, don't forget to replace `000.000.000.00` in the url.

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /* <-- ignore this, please

:: batch portion

@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0"') do (
    set mac=%%I
    set ip=%%J
)

start "" "http://000.000.000.00/defaulta.php?mac=%mac::=%&ip=%ip%"

goto :EOF

:: JScript portion  (leave this weird bit here, please) --> */

var wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\cimv2");
var adapters = wmi.InstancesOf("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
for (var res=new Enumerator(adapters); !res.atEnd(); res.moveNext()) {
    var adapter = res.item();

    /* -------------------------------------------------------------
    Note to supergaijin: If this script fails like all the others,
    try removing "|| !adapter.DNSDomain" from the following line so
    it reads as follows:  if (!adapter.IPEnabled) continue;
    ------------------------------------------------------------- */

    if (!adapter.IPEnabled || !adapter.DNSDomain) continue;
    WSH.Echo(adapter.MACAddress + ' ' + adapter.IPAddress.toArray()[0]);
}
```

Credits: I stumbled upon the `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` class using [WMI Explorer](http://www.ks-soft.net/hostmon.eng/wmi/).  I figured out how to query its child instances with the help of [Scriptomatic](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12028) (which was much more useful than the TechNet documentation).

Comment: I made sure to put a space on the xp vm but it made no difference in my original test.  I'll test what you've created and give feedback shortly.  thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: ok, it's working great on my win7 computer, but it still fails on my xp vm.  I don't have a "pure" xp machine to test it on, but if it's an issue only with xp (either in vm or "pure") I won't sweat it since only a few businesspeople are still using it in most cases.  overall this helps me save time by eliminating typo errors and bypassing language barriers.  thanks alot for the help!

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that.  The output of `ipconfig /all` in XP says `IP Address` rather than `IPv4 Address` if I recall correctly.  I'll update my example.  Does the updated version work better on XP?

Comment: I have no idea why, but the "str" you added to the "find" in the ip line broke the bat.  same with the "*" and the brackets.  it only works if I use the original bat script with "IPv4" for win7, and it works if I use "IP" for xp.  unless there's another way to cover the variables of IP vs IPv4, I'll just use two files, one for xp and one for win7.  thanks again for your help!  now if only there was a way for macs, too...

Comment: I changed the findstr string's space to a dot.  Try it now.  I believe it'll work now.  Apparently if there's a space in the search string, findstr will treat it as an `or`.  So the `for` loop was matching `/(IP(v4)?|Address)/`, where I expected it to match `/IP(v4)? Address/` in more sensible regexp terms.  Sorry about that.  I was messing with that from my mobile phone last night.  Now that I'm at an actual PC, I can troubleshoot properly.

Comment: with that latest update, on win7 it exited at "Couldn't scrape info.  Exiting.", and I had to screen cap at the right time to see 'cause it exited so fast.  on xp it didn't display anything and just exited.

Comment: Did you remember to change xxxx.net with your hotel's domain?  It tested fine for me.

Comment: silly me, that was all it needed (on my own computer at home at least).  Thanks again for all your hard work!  I'll give more feedback after I get to use it when assisting a guest at the hotel.

Comment: I forgot to ask if this would only work on an account with admin rights.  I've tried it on 3 computers and it didn't work on any of them.  if it requires admin rights, then it's no big deal, I'll just keep tying it by hand each time :P

Comment: are .bats restricted to admin only?

Comment: @supergaijin - Batch files work fine for non-privileged users (given that the commands within the batch files do not require elevation).  More details are in the update I just added to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: alright, I'll try the other style and see how it works.  just curious, do you know anything like batch files that can be used on macs as well?  I do occasionally deal with guests using macs.  I would have been able to give some feedback already if I hadn't had a mac as my last "customer" for getting the internet working :p

Comment: I believe Macs are close enough to UNIX that they can run sh scripts.  But I think they need to be made executable after downloading, so they might not be as worthwhile for the technologically challenged as .bat scripts for Windows users.  Really, if I were you, I would be more interested in getting the client mac and IP from the router or switch than from the client.  Then it wouldn't matter if they're on windows, Mac, Linux, an xbox or whatever else.

Comment: since the IT guy from the ISP only uses the same address I use, or chose not to reveal any more info the one time he showed me how to get a guest's internet working, I can't go that deep myself :P   I just tried both .bats again on one guest's computer.  the original one happened to exit slow enough I saw that even though I had the IP address and isp (xxxx.net), it exited with "can't scrape...".  the other one did open a browser, but it left the mac and ip addresses listed as variables, not a mac or ip address.  i.e., the mac showed as set %mac::=% and the ip as ip=%ip:~2,-3%.  on my computer,

Comment: ~continued...   it shows an extra mac address after the ip address, which doesn't match my ethernet mac address.

Comment: @supergaijin - What is the output of this command on your test computer?  `wmic nicconfig where (ipenabled='TRUE' and dnsdomain is not null) get ipaddress, macaddress /format:list`

Comment: my bad, it's outputting my ipv6 address after my ipv4 address, not an extra mac address.  too tired to see that yesterday :P   so on my computer, when it generates the address, it's including the ipv6 address, but for whatever reason, when it's a guest computer, it's ignoring the ipv4 and simply showing the designated variables...

Comment: so would you have any idea why it's outputting my ipv6 address after the ipv4 address, and why it refuses to work on other computers and output the variables themselves instead of any addresses?

Comment: @supergaijin - Sorry about that.  I forgot I disabled IPv6 on my own machine so my results weren't typical.  I just realized that my home computer still has IPv6 enabled and I could use it as a model for my script.  I just updated the script at the bottom of my answer.  See whether that works better for you now.

Comment: that works fine on my computer now, but I'll have to wait a bit longer for someone else to need it at work and isn't restricted by their admin.  an interesting thing happened today: a soldier was trying to get on the internet and I was unable to use cmd, disable/reenable their LAN, or even view the properties of the LAN.  he couldn't even make a bookmark in his browser in case he had issues after I finally got him on.  the restrictions made by their admins are quite severe...  I had to have him save the url in a .txt on his desktop in case he needed it again, lol

Comment: it still isn't filling in the mac and ip variables when used on a guest's computer.  any ideas?

Comment: @supergaijin - Yep.  Was the guest's computer running win XP home? Since I answered this question I've learned that `wmic` is available on XP pro and newer but not XP home.  I added a new script at the bottom of my answer.  Give it a shot.

Comment: no, the latest guest was actually running windows 8 on a netbook. I'll try that one next, thanks!