# Showing SVN Revision number in coldfusion

Tags: svn, coldfusion

I want to get the latest svn revision number using coldfusion. Any idea how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the last revision number in SVN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579196/getting-the-last-revision-number-in-svn)

Comment: did you mean <cfexecute arguments="svn info svn-url" name="svnTest" ></cfexecute>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have to parse the results, like this:
(May vary depending on your SVN app and whether on Windows or Linux)

```
<cfexecute name="c:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\svn.exe" timeout="30"
            arguments="--username myusername --password mypassword info ""c:\inetpub\mysite\"""
            variable="res"></cfexecute>

<cfset a = listToArray(res,chr(10))>


<cfset rev=0>
<cfloop array="#a#" index="i">
    <cfset info = listToArray(i,":")>
    <cfif info[1] eq "Last Changed Rev">
            <cfset rev=trim(info[2])>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>#rev#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfset workcopyPath = "[path to svn working copy]">
<cfset svnPath = "[path to svn executable]">
<cfset svnArg = " info #workcopyPath#">

<cfexecute name="#svnPath#"
           arguments="#svnArg#"
           timeout="10"
           variable="svnInfoResult">

<cfdump var=#svnInfoResult#>
```

http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2006/12/9/ColdFsion-handling-of-Subversion-events

http://www.numtopia.com/terry/blog/archives/2008/02/using_coldfusion_and_svn_to_create_release_notes.cfm

Comment: I found this article here and it explains everything very well - http://obligious.blogspot.com/2011/12/you-can-access-svn-information-from.html