# Is it possible to read number of last revision in SVN with maven?

Tags: java, svn, maven, build, revision

I use Maven to create builds.
Always takes time and produce many errors to find which last revision number was included in the build. I was thinking of something like:

```
 svn update >output.txt
```

The last line will include revision number.
But this solution doesn't seem very useful. Does exist may be mvn plugin that does update from SVN and make build and write may be in some properties file: revision, build number of libraries in projects, etc.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the last revision number in SVN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579196/getting-the-last-revision-number-in-svn)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be looking at [Build Number Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/).  This meets some of your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
svn info --xml
```

Parse xml from output and retrieve revision number