# how can I get the SVN head version number in shell?

Tags: svn

I use svn in command line.
How can I get the head version number in command line. I need the number,not only to see the info . I want to use this number to build my project automatic.

Comment: Just in case you're interested in the *revision number*: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579196/getting-the-last-revision-number-in-svn

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the comment below mentioned, this can be achieved by the following command in the newer SVN clients:

```bash
svn info -rHEAD --show-item revision
```

---

*Original Answer*

Here is simple shell script thingy for you. Execute: `svn info -rHEAD | grep Revision | cut -d' ' -f2`

See it in action:

```
main$ svn info -rHEAD
Path: main
URL: svn://url/trunk/main
Repository Root: svn://url
Repository UUID: xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
Revision: 17042
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Author: Nishant
Last Changed Rev: 17040
Last Changed Date: 2012-08-09 11:29:05 +0530 (Thu, 09 Aug 2012)

main$ svn info -rHEAD | grep Revision | cut -d' ' -f2
17042
```

**Edit1:** updated to fetch head rev.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is just I want！ Thank you angain! @Nishant

Comment: Note that modern `svn` has support for this without having to grep and cut: `svn info -rHEAD --show-item revision`