# SVN revision keywords

Tags: svn

With respect to a specific working copy path, **is there a way to check the exact revision numbers that `HEAD, BASE, COMMITTED, PREV` each refers to?**

For example, I'd like to answer the question *What revision number does keyword COMMITTED refer to, for file `foo.txt`*?

---

One way to do this, is `svn diff -r COMMITTED foo.txt`, the output of which tells me `COMMITTED` refers to revision 47245. I wonder if there is a more straightforward way.

```
Index: run.js
===================================================================
--- run.js      (revision 47245)
+++ run.js      (working copy)
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [how can I get the SVN head version number in shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878258/how-can-i-get-the-svn-head-version-number-in-shell)

To get the revision number that `HEAD` refers to. Same goes for `BASE/COMMITTED/PREV`.

```
svn info -r HEAD pom.xml | grep Revision | cut -d' ' -f2
```