# How to catch the last revision commit using svn prompt commands?

Tags: svn

I'd like to write a script which catch a revision of the last commit and save this in a file.

I'd want to know how can I do to catch the last commit revision using svn commands.

Thanks.

Comment: you want to get the revision number like `123` and save that to a file?

Comment: Yes, how to save I'll think after. For now I'd like just to know how to catch the revision number. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$ svn log -rHEAD $REPO | awk 'NR==2 {print substr($1,2)}'  > lastrev.txt
```

The `$svn log -rHEAD $REPO` prints the log of the HEAD revision of your repository.

The `awk 'NR==2' prints the second line of that log entry which happens to contain the revision number.

That revision number is the *first field* of that line, but it starts with an `r`. To remove the `r`, we use`substr($1,2)` which removes the first character of *field #1*. That strips away the `r` and leaves the rest of the revision.

Then, we redirect the output to your file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Working Copy You can also use `svnversion` command which comes with subversion
Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/579289/377854