# Get subversion's revision number for specific tag

Tags: svn

I'm getting conflicting numbers when it comes to the revision number. Let's say I run the following two commands. The most recent tag is "XYZ."

```
svn log $REPO_URL/$PATH/tags/ --limit=1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r16557 | userx | 2014-12-11 00:27:05 -0400 (Thu, 11 Dec 2014) | 1 line

svn log $REPO_URL/$PATH/tags/XYZ --limit=1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r16556 | userx | 2014-12-11 00:24:14 -0400 (Thu, 11 Dec 2014) | 1 line
```

My question is, which revision number do I care for? What I'm looking to do is to run the following command against it to see what changes were made since the last tag was created. I've tried using both numbers and they return the same result. I wasn't sure which one is the "right" one to use.

```
svn log -r<REVISION NUMBER>:HEAD $REPO_URL/$PATH/branches/$BRANCH_NAME
```

Comment: Try also using `-v` to see what changed in each revision...maybe that will clear things up. But I have no idea what's going on from the information here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the last revision number in SVN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579196/getting-the-last-revision-number-in-svn)

Answer (score 0):

If you have two different revisions for a path and a subpath, the parent path will always have the higher revision. It means that the parent path (or another subpath than the one your are looking at) was changed later.

In your case it means that `$REPO_URL/$PATH/tags/XYZ` was *not* the last change to `$REPO_URL/$PATH/tags/` or any of its subdirectories. Use `-v` as suggested by @Ben to find out what was changed.