# How to get the HEAD revision number of a given repository using svn?

Tags: svn

I want to create a Qt app which, among other things, will display the current revision number (that is the HEAD revision number) of a particular repository URL. With the help of `svn help` and [this](http://wiki.greenstone.org/wiki/index.php/Useful_SVN_Commands) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579196/getting-the-last-revision-number-in-svn), I was able to almost get what I want by calling the command `svn info <repository-url>`. The problem is that this command return lots of unwanted info (such as "last changed author", etc.), while I want *only* the revision number (or as much as few text as possible).

So how can I do it?

Comment: In your SO link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579196/getting-the-last-revision-number-in-svn), there is answer which returns HEAD rev number only: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19388054/1023562.

Comment: @IvanJovovic \o/ No comments! xD Although the guy forgot to put the <repository-url> part in the code (that one only works if you're calling svn from within a working copy). Btw, you may put write that code (with the <repository-url> included) as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per comments, to get the HEAD revision number of a given repository using svn:

```
svn info <repository-url> -r 'HEAD' | grep Revision | egrep -o "[0-9]+"
```

Comment: Use `--show-item revision` to avoid the grep: `REV=\`svn info 'https://repo-url/blah.txt' -r HEAD --show-item revision\`; echo $REV`. Prints something like `735`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you write "of a particular repository URL", is your aim to get the revision number of the last change of that specific URL (e.g. of a branch)? If so, sou might be interested in `Last Changed Rev` instead of `Revision`.

The `Revision` refers to the root repository, so it might not be what you want if you use the URL of a branch: the returned `Revision` field is the same regardless the branch specified in the URL.

In any case, as @vijucat mentioned in a comment, a cleaner way to retrieve the revision is to add `--show-item`, which supports either `revision` or `last-changed-revision`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
For a repo named "repo":

```
svnlook youngest repo
```

Comment: This one works on server repo, too, while `svn info` returns `svn: E155007: <repo> is not a working copy` in this case.