# How do I get svn revision information using command line on Windows

Tags: windows, svn, command-line

I'm trying to get the revision information for the head using this command line

```
svn info https://myserver/branches/Code_Improvements -rHEAD | find "Revision"
```

However, this returns **Revision : 1234**

Since I'm using the result of the svn info command to set a variable in my batch file, is there a way I can get just the number **1234**, instead of response **Revision : 1234**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the last revision number in SVN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579196/getting-the-last-revision-number-in-svn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this in order to get revision information in my case

```
for /f "delims=: tokens=1,2" %%a in ('svn info %SVN_REPO_URL%') do (
  if "%%a"=="Revision" (
    set /a RELEASE_REVISION=%%b
  )
)
```

Thanks @bahrep for an alternate solution. But the above snippet is what I used to get the version information in a variable.

Answer (score 12):

- Update Subversion client to 1.9 and use new [`--show-item` option](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.9.html#svn-info-item):

  ```
  svn info --show-item=revision URL-to-repository.
  ```
- As an alternative, you can get the XMLed output of `svn info` using `--xml` option and use PowerShell to get the revision number. Here is a simple example:

  ```
  [xml]$revnum = svn info <REPOSITORY-URL> --xml -r HEAD
  $latestrevnum = $revnum.info.entry.revision
  $latestrevnum
  ```

Comment: Interesting solution :) but is there a complete command-lines solution option to set to variable

Comment: It doesn't recognise the line [xml]$revnum, probably PowerShell dependency ?

Comment: @this-Me make sure that you use up-to-date PowerShell version. I guess that [xml] accelerator was not included in older PowerShell versions.

Comment: I have to use this on a build PC not sure I can add this.

Comment: `svn info --show-item=revision URL-to-repository` should probably be the correct answer by now.

Comment: @AlexSanséau thank you! I've just updated the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, if you need to get svn revision and then set it into a variable in a batch file (Windows):

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%R in ('svn info --show-item=revision URL-to-repository') do @set svnRevision=%%R
echo SVN revision: %svnRevision%
```