# How to get sparse checkout path details in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, git-svn

I am a beginner and not aware of much about SVN, Initially, I created an empty workspace  via svn sparse checkout,

```
svn co --depth empty project_url/trunk my_local_work
```

and pulled the folder where I need to change my code

```
svn up --parents Parent/Children1/Children2/Children3
```

Now, I have N number of workspace which is pulled with a different folder. How I can know which folder I have pulled using svn commands?

Is there any command which should return the sparse checkout paths?

Example: In the above, I have sparse checkout Parent/Children1/Children2/Children3 when running some commands it should return this path as output

```
Parent/Children1/Children2/Children3
```

How I can achieve this? Please let me know if need more info

In ***git***, we enable sparse checkout `git config core.sparsecheckout true` and we add the path which we need to pull from git master

```
echo Parent/Children1/Children2/Children3 >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
```

In this case we can know the sparse checkout location via `.git/info/sparse-checkout` file

When we do

```
:~ cat .git/info/sparse-checkout

Parent/Children1/Children2/Children3
```

It returns all the path details, similar I am looking for in SVN

Answer (score 0):

From command-line, you can start with [`svn info`](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/fr/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html) (with [`--show-item` option for SVN 1.9+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32115507/6309))

From TortoiseSVN, you can [check the folder properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21939074/6309).

Comment: I am using svn version 1.13.0 (r1867053), I am not able to get exactly which key I have to pass to --show-item to pull sparse checkout paths details. Only for fetch revision, URL which existed in svn info I was able to fetch using svn info --show-item=revision 
Could you please let me know the key which I have to pass --show-item=?

Comment: @NatarajaB As mention [in the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21939074/6309), `--show-item=revision`

Comment: It returns the revision number 

svn info --show-item=revision
133430 ,

I want sparse checkout path details, not revision id details. EX: Parent/Children1/Children2/Children3

Comment: @NatarajaB Would `--show-item=relative-url` help?

Comment: Nope, it will return always ^/trunk  if we run the command from my_local_work

Comment: @NatarajaB So full URL then? `--show-item=url`

Comment: Tried but no luck, I have rephrased my question