# Is there a way reading file svn revision via c++?

Tags: c++, svn, tortoisesvn

Is there a way that C++ can read some external file SVN revision in some repository?

Comment: You can use the system command and launch svn. I believe `svn info` and capture the result. Although there may be a better way. I have not done something like this in over a decade.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579196/getting-the-last-revision-number-in-svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579196/getting-the-last-revision-number-in-svn)